# Flex - TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@bcb8291 to mx.events.CloseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, flex4, puremvc

Am getting error while loading the data in popup .

Error :-

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@bcb8291 to mx.events.CloseEvent.
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()
    at com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view::AvlMediator/onAutoConfirmUploadPtaFile()[D:\ravi\new_latest\ePCN\Application\src\main\flex\com\nxp\pcn\modules\avl\view\AvlMediator.as:219]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()
    at com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view.components.popups::AvlUploadPopup/set stats()[D:\ravi\new_latest\ePCN\Application\src\main\flex\com\nxp\pcn\modules\avl\view\components\popups\AvlUploadPopup.mxml:138]
    at com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view::AvlMediator/validateUploadedProducts()[D:\ravi\new_latest\ePCN\Application\src\main\flex\com\nxp\pcn\modules\avl\view\AvlMediator.as:339]
    at com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view::AvlMediator/handleNotification()[D:\ravi\new_latest\ePCN\Application\src\main\flex\com\nxp\pcn\modules\avl\view\AvlMediator.as:312]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at org.puremvc.as3.multicore.patterns.observer::Observer/notifyObserver()[C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\workspaces\PureMVC\PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore\src\org\puremvc\as3\multicore\patterns\observer\Observer.as:100]
    at org.puremvc.as3.multicore.core::View/notifyObservers()[C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\workspaces\PureMVC\PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore\src\org\puremvc\as3\multicore\core\View.as:114]
    at org.puremvc.as3.multicore.patterns.facade::Facade/notifyObservers()[C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\workspaces\PureMVC\PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore\src\org\puremvc\as3\multicore\patterns\facade\Facade.as:294]
    at org.puremvc.as3.multicore.patterns.facade::Facade/sendNotification()[C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\workspaces\PureMVC\PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore\src\org\puremvc\as3\multicore\patterns\facade\Facade.as:277]
    at org.puremvc.as3.multicore.patterns.observer::Notifier/sendNotification()[C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\workspaces\PureMVC\PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore\src\org\puremvc\as3\multicore\patterns\observer\Notifier.as:60]
    at com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.model::AvlProxy/uploadProductsResult()[D:\ravi\new_latest\ePCN\Application\src\main\flex\com\nxp\pcn\modules\avl\model\AvlProxy.as:77]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.rpc::AbstractOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()
    at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()
    at mx.rpc::Responder/result()
    at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()
    at NetConnectionMessageResponder/resultHandler()
    at mx.messaging::MessageResponder/result()

And i am uploading code here.

package com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view
{
    import com.evelopers.flex.components.placedmodule.view.components.ModulePlaceholder;
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import com.evelopers.flex.components.Confirmator;
    import com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view.components.Avl;
    import com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view.components.renderers.AvlPartNumberRenderer;

```
import com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view.components.popups.AvlUploadPopup;
import com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view.components.popups.ManageActivationPopup;
import com.nxp.pcn.shell.model.vo.AvlProductVO;
import com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.AvlConstants;
import com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view.components.sf.searchAvl;
import com.nxp.pcn.shell.interfaces.IDictionaryVO;
import flash.events.Event;
import com.nxp.pcn.shell.ApplicationConstants;
import com.nxp.pcn.shell.model.SessionUserProxy;

import org.puremvc.as3.multicore.interfaces.INotification;
import org.puremvc.as3.multicore.patterns.mediator.Mediator;
import com.evelopers.flex.modules.ValueListModule;
import com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view.AddAvlProductMediator;
import com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.view.ManageActivationPopupMediator;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.utils.setTimeout;
import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
import com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.model.vo.AvlAttachmentVO;
import com.evelopers.flex.utils.PopupUtils;
import com.nxp.pcn.modules.avl.model.vo.AvlUploadStatsVO;
import com.nxp.pcn.shell.helpers.Tracer;
import com.nxp.pcn.shell.view.components.ProductDescriptionPopup;
import com.evelopers.flex.utils.PopupUtils;
import com.nxp.pcn.shell.model.SessionUserProxy;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import com.evelopers.flex.helpers.SmartEvent;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import mx.utils.StringUtil;
import com.nxp.pcn.shell.model.vo.CompanyVO;

public class AvlMediator extends Mediator
{
    public static const NAME:String = "AvlMediator";
    private var _sessionUserProxy:SessionUserProxy;
    private var _dicts:Object = {};
    public var _productsToRemove:Array;
    private var _uploadAvlPopup : AvlUploadPopup;

    public var avlCompanies : ArrayCollection;

    public function AvlMediator(viewComponent:Avl)
    {
        super(NAME, viewComponent);
    }

    override public function onRegister():void {
        // Retrieve the proxies
        _sessionUserProxy = facade.retrieveProxy(SessionUserProxy.NAME) as SessionUserProxy;

        // Create and register Mediators
        component.addEventListener(Avl.REJECT, onReject);
        component.addEventListener(Avl.REJECT_UPLOAD, onRejectUpload);
        component.addEventListener(Avl.UPLOAD, onUpload);
        component.addEventListener(Avl.ADD_PRODUCT, onAddProduct);
        component.addEventListener(Avl.REMOVE_PRODUCT, onRemoveProduct);
        component.addEventListener(Avl.DOWNLOAD_AVL_TEMPLATE, onDownloadAvlTemplate);
        component.addEventListener(Avl.MANAGE_ACTIVATION, onManageActivation);
        component.addEventListener(AvlPartNumberRenderer.VIEW_PRODUCT_DETAILS, onViewProductDetails);
        //component.addEventListener(ManageActivationPopupMediator.POPUP_REMOVED, onManageActivationPopupRemoved);

        // Register view handlers
        sendNotification(ApplicationConstants.GET_SESSION_USER);
        sendNotification(ApplicationConstants.REQUEST_DICTIONARY, ApplicationConstants.dicts.CUSTOMER_ACTIVE_COMPANIES);
        sendNotification(AvlConstants.GET_AVL_COMPANIES);

        // register Mediators
        facade.registerMediator(new AddAvlProductMediator());
        facade.registerMediator(new ManageActivationPopupMediator());

    }

    public function get selectedOrg():CompanyVO
    {
        return component.selectedOrg;
    }

    private function onDownloadAvlTemplate(event:Event):void
    {
        Tracer.trace(this, sf.sessionUser, 'session user');
        Tracer.trace(this, StringUtil.substitute(ApplicationConstants.urls.AVL_SPECIFIC_EXPORT_SERVLET, ApplicationConstants.valueLists.AVL_PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_VL), 'on download avl template');
        ExternalInterface.call('downloadFile',
            StringUtil.substitute(ApplicationConstants.urls.AVL_SPECIFIC_EXPORT_SERVLET,
                ApplicationConstants.valueLists.AVL_PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_VL));
    }

    private function onRejectUpload(event:Event):void
    {
        sendNotification(AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_UPLOAD_REJECT_QUERY);
    }
    /*

    */
    /*
    private function onManageActivationPopupRemoved(e:Event):void
    {
        Tracer.trace(this, 'onManageActivationPopupRemoved', 'AvlMediator');
        facade.removeMediator(ManageActivationPopupMediator.NAME);
    }
    */

    private function onUpload(e:Event):void
    {
        PopupUtils.addFixedPopup(uploadAvlPopup, FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject, true);
        uploadAvlPopup.updateView();
    }

    private function onManageActivation(e:Event):void
    {
        sendNotification(AvlConstants.ADD_MANAGE_ACTIVATION_POPUP);
        /*
        var detailsPopup:ManageActivationPopup = new ManageActivationPopup();
        //detailsPopup.productData = event.data;
        //detailsPopup.sessionUser = (facade.retrieveProxy(SessionUserProxy.NAME) as SessionUserProxy).userVO;
        PopupUtils.addFixedPopup(detailsPopup, this.component, true);
        */
    }

    private function onViewProductDetails(event:SmartEvent):void {
        var detailsPopup:ProductDescriptionPopup = new ProductDescriptionPopup();
        detailsPopup.productData = event.data;
        detailsPopup.sessionUser = (facade.retrieveProxy(SessionUserProxy.NAME) as SessionUserProxy).userVO;
        PopupUtils.addFixedPopup(detailsPopup, event.target as DisplayObject, true);
    }

    public function get uploadAvlPopup():AvlUploadPopup {
        if (_uploadAvlPopup == null) {
            _uploadAvlPopup = new AvlUploadPopup();
            _uploadAvlPopup.addEventListener(AvlUploadPopup.AUTO_CONFIRM_UPLOAD, onAutoConfirmUploadPtaFile);
            _uploadAvlPopup.addEventListener(AvlUploadPopup.CONFIRM_UPLOAD, onConfirmUploadPta);
            _uploadAvlPopup.addEventListener(AvlUploadPopup.REJECT_UPLOAD, onRejectUploadPta);

            _uploadAvlPopup.addEventListener(AvlUploadPopup.UPLOAD_FILE, onUploadPtaFile);
            var orgs:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( ObjectUtil.copy(avlCompanies.source) as Array);
            //orgs.removeItemAt(0);
            _uploadAvlPopup.organizations = orgs;

            //Tracer.trace(this, selectedOrg, 'selected org');

            if (selectedOrg)
            {
                for each (var org : CompanyVO in _uploadAvlPopup.organizations)
                {
                    if (org.name == selectedOrg.name)
                    {
                        setTimeout(setUploadOrg, 500, org);
                    }
                }
            }

            _uploadAvlPopup.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, function(event:Event):void
                {
                    PopUpManager.removePopUp(_uploadAvlPopup);
                    sendNotification(ApplicationConstants.CP_REJECT_PTA_UPLOAD_QUERY);
                    _uploadAvlPopup = null;
                });
        }
        return _uploadAvlPopup;
    }

    private function setUploadOrg(org:CompanyVO):void
    {
        _uploadAvlPopup.companyCombo.selectedItem = org;
        _uploadAvlPopup.companyCombo.text = org.name;
    }

    private function onConfirmUploadPta(event:Event):void 
    {
        PopUpManager.removePopUp(_uploadAvlPopup);
        sendNotification(AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_UPLOAD_CONFIRM_QUERY, true);
    }

    private function onRejectUploadPta(event:Event):void 
    {
        PopUpManager.removePopUp(_uploadAvlPopup);
        sendNotification(AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_UPLOAD_REJECT_QUERY);        
    }

    private function onUploadPtaFile(event:Event):void {
        var att:AvlAttachmentVO = new AvlAttachmentVO();
        att.companyId = _uploadAvlPopup.companyCombo.selectedItem.id;
        att.fileReference = uploadAvlPopup.fileReferenceVO;            
        sendNotification(AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_UPLOAD_QUERY, att);

        Tracer.trace(this, att, 'upload file');

    }

    private function onAutoConfirmUploadPtaFile(event:Event):void {
        sendNotification(ApplicationConstants.INFO_MESSAGE, 'Avl file has been uploaded successfully');
        sendNotification(ApplicationConstants.INFO_MESSAGE, 'A new match has been made, organization list has been re-created.');
        uploadAvlPopup.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CLOSE));
        //reloadPcn(pcnCreation.pcnVO, CreationProductsSection.NAME);
    }

    private function onConfirmUploadPtaFile(event:Event):void {
        //sendNotification(ApplicationConstants.CP_CONFIRM_UPLOAD_PTA_QUERY, true);
    }

    private function onRejectUploadPtaFile(event:Event):void {
        //sendNotification(ApplicationConstants.CP_CONFIRM_UPLOAD_PTA_QUERY, false);
    }


    private function onReject(event:Event):void
    {
        sendNotification(AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_REJECT_QUERY);
    }

    private function onAddProduct(e:Event):void
    {
        sendNotification(AvlConstants.AVL_ADD_PRODUCT_POPUP);
    }

    private function onRemoveProduct(e:Event):void
    {
        var fullData:ArrayCollection = avl.vlStateData.fullData;
        _productsToRemove = []; // <AvlProductVO>
        for each (var record : Object in fullData)
        {
            if (record['isSelected'])
            {
                _productsToRemove.push(new AvlProductVO(uint(record['companyId']), record['nc12']));
            }
        }

        if (_productsToRemove.length == 0) return;

        if (fullData.length == _productsToRemove.length && _productsToRemove.length > 1) 
        {
            // Gonna delete ALL distributors
            new Confirmator('Remove Products confirmation',
                'You are about to remove ALL products\nPress "OK" to proceed',
                Confirmator.OK_CANCEL, removeAllProducts);
        } else {
            new Confirmator('Remove Products confirmation',
                'You are about to remove ' + _productsToRemove.length + ' product(s)\nPress "OK" to proceed',
                Confirmator.OK_CANCEL, removeProducts);
        }

    }

    private function removeProducts(event:Event):void 
    {
        sendNotification(AvlConstants.AVL_REMOVE_PRODUCTS_QUERY, _productsToRemove);
        _productsToRemove = null;
    }

    private function removeAllProducts(event:Event):void 
    {
        sendNotification(AvlConstants.AVL_REMOVE_PRODUCTS_QUERY);
    }

    override public function listNotificationInterests():Array 
    {
        return [
            ApplicationConstants.RESPONSE_DICTIONARY,
            AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_ADD_CONFIRMED,
            AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_ADD_CONFIRMED_RESULT,
            AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_REJECT_QUERY,
            AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_DELETED,
            AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_UPLOAD_QUERY_RESULT,
            AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_UPLOAD_CONFIRMED,
            AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_UPLOAD_QUERY_FAULT,
            AvlConstants.GET_AVL_COMPANIES_RESULT

        ];
    }

    override public function handleNotification(note:INotification):void 
    {
        switch (note.getName()) 
        {
            case ApplicationConstants.RESPONSE_DICTIONARY:
            var dict:IDictionaryVO = note.getBody() as IDictionaryVO;
            switch (dict.getName()) 
            {
                case ApplicationConstants.dicts.CUSTOMER_ACTIVE_COMPANIES:
                _dicts[ApplicationConstants.dicts.CUSTOMER_ACTIVE_COMPANIES] = dict;
                sf.organizations = dict.filter;
                break;
            }
            break;
            case AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_UPLOAD_QUERY_RESULT:
            validateUploadedProducts(note);
            break;
            case AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_UPLOAD_QUERY_FAULT:
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(_uploadAvlPopup);
            break;
            case AvlConstants.GET_AVL_COMPANIES_RESULT:
            //Tracer.trace(this, note.getBody(), 'GET_AVL_COMPANIES_RESULT');
            avlCompanies = ArrayCollection(note.getBody());
            if(avlCompanies.length > 0){
                avl.hasAvlCompanies = true;
            }
            break;
            case AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_UPLOAD_CONFIRMED:
            case AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_ADD_CONFIRMED_RESULT:
            case AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_ADD_CONFIRMED:
            avl.vlSearchAvl.dispatchEvent(new Event(ValueListModule.DO_SEARCH));
            break;
            case AvlConstants.PRODUCTS_DELETED:
            sendNotification(ApplicationConstants.INFO_MESSAGE, 'Avl product(s) were removed successfully');
            avl.vlSearchAvl.dispatchEvent(new Event(ValueListModule.DO_SEARCH));
            break;
        }
    }

    private function validateUploadedProducts(note:INotification):void
    {
        var stats : AvlUploadStatsVO = AvlUploadStatsVO(note.getBody());
        uploadAvlPopup.stats = stats;

        if (!uploadAvlPopup.isAutoConfirm()) 
        {
            PopupUtils.addFixedPopup(uploadAvlPopup, component, true);
        }
    }

    public function insertUI(placeholder:ModulePlaceholder):void 
    {
        component.sessionUser = _sessionUserProxy.getSessionUser();

        if (!component.sessionUser) {
            return;
        }

        placeholder.addChild(component);
    }       

    private function get component():Avl 
    {
        return viewComponent as Avl;
    }

    private function get avl():Avl
    {
        return component;
    }

    private function get sf():searchAvl
    {
        return component.sf;
    }
    public function getCurrentOrg():int
    {
        if (sf.searchFilter.obj.companyId == null)
        {
            return -1;
        } else
        {
            return sf.searchFilter.obj.companyId.id;
        }

    }

}
```

}

Please let me know where the issue and how to resolve it.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Sometimes you get type conflicts if you are working with modules and the browser is loading an older module version from the cache. In this case you should clear your browser cache and see what happens.

Comment: i have tried the same ..but it gives the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

You should dispatch your close event with the `CloseEvent` class in your `onAutoConfirmUploadPtaFile` function. Instead of

```
uploadAvlPopup.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CLOSE));
```

you should write

```
uploadAvlPopup.dispatchEvent(new CloseEvent(Event.CLOSE));
```

Otherwise a corresponding handler will stumble above the `Event` class while it is expecting a `CloseEvent` class.